# Select from table where updated_at + 15minutes <= this_datetime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I am seaching for a solution in Laravel 5 (eloquent) to select records form a table where updated_at + 15 minutes <= today (actual datetime).

I try this solution but it does not work :

```
$albums = Album::with(array('pictures' => function($q){
            $q->whereDate('updated_at','<=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - (15*60)));
        }))->get();
```

The result look always empty

```
dd($albums->pictures)
```

Comment: and it's look bit of horrible, why not use carbon to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$currentTime = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(15);
```

above will give you equivalent to this mess 'date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - (15*60))'

I still don't understand why you need these 15 minute operation? But any way try this and let us know outcome.

```
$albums = Album::with(array('pictures' => function($q){
    $currentTime = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(15);
    $q->whereDate('updated_at','<=', $currentTime));
}))->get();
```